# XPages - multiple clicks creates multiple documents

Tags: xpages

My form has two submit buttons - one for the submit and one to update the document.  There is an agent which runs on the PostSaveDocument event.  In this agent, there is a bunch of code which sends a few alerts, and sets some document values, depending on whether or not it's a new document or an update to the document.

When the user clicks the button multiple times, eg double clicks or just goes skitzo and clicks 10 times, then that number of documents are generated.  In the code, it creates a reference number, and this number is sequential for the number of times the button is clicked - so it is queuing up the number of times it is clicked.

I have tried two options:

- run the following code when the button is clicked, but it does not stop the multiple clicks going through.

  ```
  var buttonComp = getComponent("button4");
  buttonComp.setDisabled(true);
  ```
- Checked this post http://dontpanic82.blogspot.com.au/2010/06/xpages-avoid-saving-duplicate-documents.html

However neither works for me.  I assume it's because it's not dealing with a standard submit form, but am not sure.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try disabling the button in the client-side onClick event (using client-side JS, of course)

Comment: I have used the CSJS "document1.getElementById("button4").disabled = true", and now the form does not submit.  I usually use SSJS, is my syntax wrong? (apologies for what i suspect is a dumb question). Would the CSJS stop the SSJS from executing?

Comment: CSJS runs before SSJS. CSJS needs to return true or false. False will stop SSJS from running, while true will allow SSJS to run. So try adding a "return true" after disabling the button.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have multiple datasources setup that point to the same document.

Comment: I added 'return true', and the code now 'runs', however it does not disable the button, and multiple clicks still cause multiple documents to be created.  I have moved the code to a new button, put in in the 'execute script' for CSJS yet it does not work.  I have also tried '.visible = false' instead of '.disabled = true' and neither work?

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with Stephan on converting the agent to SSJS.

But if you cant change that code, try using [busy button](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/form/BusyButton.html).

Comment: This looks great - but I am not 100% sure how to use the button within an xPage.  I have only really used std xpage controls.  Starting to investigate this - managed to create a dojo button (yes, not hard), but was not sure when where to use the source code to change the text etc.  Where does the code in the <head></head> go for the xPage?  should it be in the client/server side events for the dojo button, or does it need to be added directly into the xPage code for the button? This may be obvious to others, but not to me right now...

Comment: I am not sure how to paste the code here.. but you have to include dojox.form.BusyButton under resources as dojomodule and assign dojo attributes data-dojo-props value busyLabel:'For 10 seconds' and another attribute timeout and its value as no of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if you can avoid don't use an agent. It is very slow to spin up the agent runtime and then tear it down again. You are probably better off writing the code in SSJS. Secondly you must write the disable code (or better visible=false) inside the onClick event (look for the client side code tab). Another option is to show a lightbox with "processing" that covers the button without disabling it.

Comment: Thanks - I did try the code above, setting visible to false, but it appears as though it still waits for the agent to run.  In saying that, when I have the code in a separate button, it does not hide it (running CSJS).  The code I added is as follows "document1.getElementById("button8").visible = false;
return true".